# Kafka Producer deployed on Kubernetes not able to produce to Kafka cluster running on local machine

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, minikube

I have a Kafka cluster running on the local machine with default settings outside of my minikube setup. I have created a producer in one of my web services and deployed it on minikube.

For producer to connect to Kafka I am using `10.0.2.2` IP which I am also using to connect Cassandra and DGraph outside of minikube for these it is working fine.

However Kafka producer is not working and not even throwing an error saying `Broker may not be available` or any other errors while sending data. But I am not receiving anything on the consumer side.

When I run this web service outside the Kubernetes everything works.

Please if you guys have any idea what might be wrong here.

Below is the `Kubernetes yaml` file that I am using.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: servicename
  labels:
    app: servicename
    metrics: kamon
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: servicename
        metrics: kamon
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: "image:app"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: servicename
        env:
        - name: CIRCUIT_BREAKER_MAX_FAILURES
          value: "10"
        - name: CIRCUIT_BREAKER_RESET_TIMEOUT
          value: 30s
        - name: CIRCUIT_BREAKER_CALL_TIMEOUT
          value: 30s
        - name: CONTACT_POINT_ONE
          value: "10.0.2.2"
        - name: DGRAPH_HOSTS
          value: "10.0.2.2"
        - name: DGRAPH_PORT
          value: "9080"
        - name: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
          value: "10.0.2.2:9092"
        - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_NOTIFICATION_CLIENT_ID
          value: "notificationProducer"
        - name: KAFKA_NOTIFICATION_TOPIC
          value: "notification"
        - name: LAGOM_PERSISTENCE_READ_SIDE_OFFSET_TIMEOUT
          value: 5s
        - name: LAGOM_PERSISTENCE_READ_SIDE_FAILURE_EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF_MIN
          value: 3s
        - name: LAGOM_PERSISTENCE_READ_SIDE_FAILURE_EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF_MAX
          value: 30s
        - name: LAGOM_PERSISTENCE_READ_SIDE_FAILURE_EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF_RANDOM_FACTOR
          value: "0.2"
        - name: LAGOM_PERSISTENCE_READ_SIDE_GLOBAL_PREPARE_TIMEOUT
          value: 30s
        - name: LAGOM_PERSISTENCE_READ_SIDE_RUN_ON_ROLE
          value: ""
        - name: LAGOM_PERSISTENCE_READ_SIDE_USE_DISPATCHER
          value: lagom.persistence.dispatcher
        - name: AKKA_TIMEOUT
          value: 30s
        - name: NUMBER_OF_DGRAPH_REPOSITORY_ACTORS
          value: "2"
        - name: DGRAPH_ACTOR_TIMEOUT_MILLIS
          value: "20000"
        - name: AKKA_ACTOR_PROVIDER
          value: "cluster"
        - name: AKKA_CLUSTER_SHUTDOWN_AFTER_UNSUCCESSFUL_JOIN_SEED_NODES
          value: 40s
        - name: AKKA_DISCOVERY_METHOD
          value: "kubernetes-api"
        - name: AKKA_IO_DNS_RESOLVER
          value: "async-dns"
        - name: AKKA_IO_DNS_ASYNC_DNS_PROVIDER_OBJECT
          value: "com.lightbend.rp.asyncdns.AsyncDnsProvider"
        - name: AKKA_IO_DNS_ASYNC_DNS_RESOLVE_SRV
          value: "true"
        - name: AKKA_IO_DNS_ASYNC_DNS_RESOLV_CONF
          value: "on"
        - name: AKKA_MANAGEMENT_HTTP_PORT
          value: "10002"
        - name: AKKA_MANAGEMENT_HTTP_BIND_HOSTNAME
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: AKKA_MANAGEMENT_HTTP_BIND_PORT
          value: "10002"
        - name: AKKA_MANAGEMENT_CLUSTER_BOOTSTRAP_CONTACT_POINT_DISCOVERY_REQUIRED_CONTACT_POINT_NR
          value: "1"
        - name: AKKA_REMOTE_NETTY_TCP_PORT
          value: "10001"
        - name: AKKA_REMOTE_NETTY_TCP_BIND_HOSTNAME
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: AKKA_REMOTE_NETTY_TCP_BIND_HOSTNAME
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: AKKA_REMOTE_NETTY_TCP_BIND_PORT
          value: "10001"
        - name: LAGOM_CLUSTER_EXIT_JVM_WHEN_SYSTEM_TERMINATED
          value: "on"
        - name: PLAY_SERVER_HTTP_ADDRESS
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: PLAY_SERVER_HTTP_PORT
          value: "9000"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        - containerPort: 9095
        - containerPort: 10001
        - containerPort: 9092
          name: "akka-remote"
        - containerPort: 10002
          name: "akka-mgmt-http"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: servicename
  labels:
    app: servicename
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "http"
      port: 9000
      nodePort: 31001
      targetPort: 9000
    - name: "akka-remote"
      port: 10001
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 10001
    - name: "akka-mgmt-http"
      port: 10002
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 10002
  selector:
    app: servicename
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Please show your service files. Kafka needs advertised listeners configuration to be exposed to outside of the k8s cluster to be ingress address

Comment: @cricket_007 My Kafka cluster is outside the K8. However, the producer is in K8.

Comment: Could you share configuration for application on Kubernetes side. It is Deployment and Service.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I have added the `yaml` file details for K8.

Comment: Could you try to reach `10.0.2.2` IP address from inside of the Pod and from minikube virtual machine? You can use ping or curl utilities.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I am already connecting to Cassandra and Dgraph running on the same machine as Kafka from inside the K8.

Comment: But what about accessing to the port which used by Kafka? And reaching Kafka from exact Pod?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev thanks Artem. But resolved the issue by adjusting Kafka configuration for `advertised.listeners`. Will answer here tomorrow, just had some beers right now :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am already connecting to Cassandra and Dgraph running on the same machine as Kafka

Well, those services don't advertise their network address via Zookeeper.

> My Kafka cluster is outside the K8. However, the producer is in K8.

In order for services outside of k8s to know Kafka's location, the `advertised.listeners` needs to be set to an external IP or DNS address that all producer/consumer services in the k8s environment will be recognize and that's the address that your services will connect to. For example `PLAINTEXT://10.0.2.2:9092`

In other words, if you had not set up the listeners, and it was only listening on localhost, just because the Kafka port is externally exposed, means that while you might be able to reach one broker, the address you get back as part of the protocol is not guaranteed to be the same thing as your client's configuration, and that's where the advertised listener address comes into play.

Comment: More information on advertised listeners can be found at https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/